# autocomplete md-angular : json from promise

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete

I am starting from the custom template in [material-angular documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete)

It works fine but in my case,I have to use a resource to get the list of datas.

If I replace

```
$scope.repos = loadAll();
```

with

```
MyFactory.getDatas().$promise.then(function(response){
        $scope.repos = response;
        console.log(response);
    });
```

I have this error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

How can I do it ? i just have to call my resource once to get the data, I don't want to call the resource each time I change the text.

EDIT : The result of rhe console.log in google chrome :

```
Array[2]
    0:m
        $$hashKey:"object:113"
        id:"2290"
        nom:"TEST 1"
        __proto__:Object
    1:m
        $$hashKey:"object:113"
        id:"2291"
        nom:"TEST 2"
        __proto__:Object
    $promise: d
        $$state:Object
        __proto__:Object
        $resolved:true
        length:59
    $resolved : true
    length : 2
```

[a plunker ok what did](http://plnkr.co/edit/54Do6GXZdKOeNBO0e13E?p=info)

Thanks

Comment: Does your `MyFactory.getDatas()` return a promise properly? That error occurs the response from `MyFactory.getDatas()` doesn't contain a `$promise` object

Comment: i added the result of my promise

Comment: Looks like a $promise it is... Would you be able to create a Plnkr with the issue?

Comment: i added a plunker link but i don't know how to code the resource

Comment: Just create a deferred promise using `$q` service and resolve it with some hard coded values in your `MyFactory.getDatas()`

Comment: ou mean in plunker ? if yes do you have an example ?  because my factory is used by other contoller, i can't change it

Comment: Can you try with `MyFactory.getDatas().promise` instead of `MyFactory.getDatas().$promise`.... Just to be sure...

Comment: same problem with .promise. I tried to find example of md-autocomplete with an initial json from a promise but i didn't find one

Comment: Can you show the getDatas() function?